# How do I conduct a audition/blindfold test of audio monitors ?

Tags: speakers, monitors, studio-monitors

I've been looking for a good description of how to audition monitors for my new studio.  I haven't found anything that describes a systematic process I can follow and also evaluation criteria at each stage.  I have heard that BBC and others have their own internal processes that they follow for these decisions where they conduct blindfold tests among many recording engineers and would enjoy learning more about how to do this.

Any guidance/links to articles would be appreciated.

Thanks
Fred Speckeen

Comment: You won't be listening to the speakers with your eyes closed will you?

Answer (score 2):

Construct a CD with 5-8 songs of different genres. Ones you really like the mix in and that you know well.

Listen how each song performs on the monitors.

Make sure the monitors are in a room that is also treated when you test them.

I see the word studio, so I will assume that there is acoustic wall treatment then.

Answer (score 0):

Take a high quality copy of a song that you know to death and listen to it on a selection of monitors.